# Why does my HP Smart Array show two logical drives as failed?

Tags: raid

I have HP Proliant DL 380 G8 with raid 0+1 ..still its not booting in smart array controller showing 2 logical drive is failed how can we fix it

[image]

Comment: You probably have some failed physical drives. Could you please check the status of these and reply back?

Answer (score 1):

**They're not failed.**

Select one the the logical drives and there will be an option for "more information".

The red alerts you see are because the logical drives can't be edited... probably because you're booted from an OS running on that array/logical drive.

Or maybe they indicate a cache problem. But the interface should clearly show the issue if you select the component with the warning sign.